# Induced map on homology of $\mathbb{R}P^n \vee \mathbb{R}P^n$ from interchanging copies of $\mathbb{R}P^n$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

I am trying to compute the homology of the mapping torus of $X = \mathbb{R}P^n \vee \mathbb{R}P^n$, where $f:X \rightarrow X$ is a map that exchanges the two copies of $\mathbb{R}P^n$; that is, $f(x,y) = (y,x)$. I can do this with exact sequences except that I don't know what the induced map $f_*$ is. What if the space is instead $X = \mathbb{C}P^3 \vee \mathbb{C}P^3$. Help?

Note: By mapping torus for a map $f:X \rightarrow X$, we mean the space $X \times [0,1]/\sim$ where $\sim$ is the equivalence $(x,0) \sim (f(x),1)$.

Comment: Convince yourself that for $i\geq 1$,  $H_i(Y\vee Y) \cong H_i(Y) \bigoplus H_i(Y)$. Then you can convince yourself that the induced map on homology from interchanges the copies, is just the switch of the associated abelian groups in the direct sum.

Comment: So you're saying that $f_*: H_i(\mathbb{R}P^n) \oplus H_i(\mathbb{R}P^n) \rightarrow  H_i(\mathbb{R}P^n) \oplus H_i(\mathbb{R}P^n)$ such that $f_*(x,y) = (y,x), correct?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: @OlesWohnzimmer Okay, and just to verify: for $i = 0$, $H_i(\mathbb{R} P^n \vee \mathbb{R} P^n) \simeq \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ since each $\mathbb{R} P^n$ is a connected component. So $f_*$ for the $i = 0$ case is given by $f_*: \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ with $f(x,y) = (y,x)$ still?

Comment: No. Since $\mathbb{R}P^n \vee \mathbb{R}P^n$ is connected, the zeroth homology is $\mathbb{Z}$ and the induced map must be the identity.